# how to add missing value on the legend in map visualization javascript?

Tags: javascript, visualization, legend, missing-data

I am trying to use map visualization and I have some missing state in my data.
[image]

I added a condition for missing value to fill the map in red. Here is my code:

```
{
  var projection = projection1; 
  
  //Create SVG element
  var mapSvg = d3.create("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

  var ramp = d3.scaleSequential().interpolator(d3.interpolateRgb("lightyellow", "green")).domain([0, 5600000])
  
  var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);
  mapSvg
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(data.features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("stroke", "white")
      .style("fill", d => hay.has(d.properties.name.toUpperCase()) ? ramp(hay.get(d.properties.name.toUpperCase())) : "red")// red for missing value
      .append('title')
      .text((d) => `${d.properties.name}\n${hay.has(d.properties.name.toUpperCase()) ? hay.get(d.properties.name.toUpperCase()) : "Missing value"}`);
  
  return mapSvg.node();
}
```

and I assigned colorScale as below to have a legend:

```
colorScale = d3.scaleSequential().interpolator(d3.interpolateRgb("lightyellow", "green")).domain([0, 5600000])
```

This is the value of colorscale :

[image: printed value of]

here I used d3 legend:

```
legend({ color: colorScale, title: "Corp Hay", tickFormat: ".02s" })
```

now my question is how to add that red color to the legend as missing value?

Comment: Please print to the console the data you pass to the legend and a picture of the current result

Comment: I just edited my post